# Is the phrase 'increasely likely' acceptable? If so, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I like to read different newspapers and news websites to pick up some English  words and phrases with which I'm unfamiliar.

I found the two-word phrase *increasely likely*, which I found confusing.

Comment: The answer from altaltpow covers the probable intended wording pretty thoroughly, and the two comments beneath that answer cover the (unasked) question of "what went wrong?" very neatly. So I don;'t see any need to reopen this question.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine they were going for "increasingly likely." Keep in mind that newspapers and websites often make terrible mistakes, "increasely likely" is not a phrase, increasely isn't even a word.

*Increasingly likely* simply means that an event becomes more and more likely to occur as time goes on.

Comment: Plus it might well be someone's transcription of someone else saying _increasingly likely_ and missing the /ɪŋ/ in the flurry of 3 Ls in a row /li'laykli/ at the end. If that transcription's gone through the ears of a speaker of a language that doesn't have Ls or often confuses them with Rs, for instance, 3 Ls in a row in one word is enough to have caused considerable stress in the transcriber, and a little syllable like /ɪŋ/ is easy to lose track of.

Comment: @JohnLawler More likely a typo/brainfart, I would have thought.